# Node.js POST request not working

Tags: php, node.js, post

My parameters in Node-Request aren't getting to its target...
I'm not finding any mistakes...

```
      var data = querystring.stringify({
      image: 'test',
      test: 'testitest'
  });

  var options = {
      host: 'www.visionalism.com',
      path: path,
      method: 'POST'
  };

var photo_req = http.request(options, function(response) {
    response.setEncoding('utf8');
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log("body: " + chunk);
    });
});
  console.log(data);
photo_req.write(data);
photo_req.end();
```

At the other side, the POST array (php) is complete empty...

Am i missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem by adding headers.... bad mistake

Comment: you should mark your solution so your question disappears from the unanswered list. :-)